# Booking barber/hairdresser appointments for multiple people

Tags: forms, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I'm working with a client that wants to allow users to book barber/hairdresser  appointments through a web app. Users will be able to book multiple appointments on different dates/times. I'm trying to work out what the best user journey would be; having users book every step for 1 appointment then move on to the next or book a step for each appointment then move on to the next step (e.g book a date for app 1 and 2, then book time for app 1 and 2, then pay for bookings)?

[image]

**EDIT**

Users will need to complete all booking information before moving onto payment

Comment: Ask your users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking from the user perspective, I think it makes the most sense to complete the first booking before starting to provide all the info needed for the second booking - unless I wanted to set up a "regular" appointment, like every 5 weeks please set up an appointment with me with Barber Joe Smith for 11:30am on Saturday.  In that case an option to repeat every x days or weeks would be ideal, like setting up a regular event in a Calendar app.

When to pay for future appointments is an interesting question.  Having to enter payment information multiple times would be a pain but perhaps the payment information could be stored like it is on Amazon and similar sites so I don't have to enter in my card details each time.

Comment: What if the user wants to book back to back appointments? Let's say I want an appointment for myself and my two sons, one after an another, does completing one booking before moving onto the next still make sense?

Comment: Depends on sophistication of the app.  Is there any situation in which for NON PAYMENT reasons the appointment request would be rejected, ie: requested barber not being available?  What I was trying to avoid was dealing with error states for more than one appointment at a time BUT if the app is very simple with not a lot of backend processing, yes, I could see "family" or "couple" appointments where the app would allowing booking simultaneous or one-after-another appointments like for a Mom and her 2 sons or husband and wife.  In that case paying once for all the appointments is a convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Like a classic e-commerce site, user should have both options:

1. Complete the booking - this is like going to shopping cart approval and then proceed to the payment.
2. Continue booking - this is like Continue shopping.

There are several approaches to how to present the user the two options. Some sites are prompting for the shopping cart approval step with every new item added to it. Some are just having it at the top updated with the number of items. Choose what's best for you. But, the answer to your question is that **user should be able to do both**.

Comment: Users aren't essentially adding items to a cart. My question is if a user wants to book three appointments, should they complete each step (type, service, date, time) for booking 1 before moving onto booking 2 then number 3 or complete one step for each booking (booking 1 type - booking 2 type - booking 3 type - booking 1 service - booking 2 service, etc) before moving on to payment

Comment: oh...in this case, option 1 makes more sense. They should complete a booking before moving to the next one. Think of the way they would have book a service by phone: you give the full details for the order then move to the next one (if you like).

Answer (score 0):

User completes one booking first and then move ons to next booking (NOT ADVISABLE, To much efforts and clicks involved at User's end)

Here is a 2 step scenario:

**Step 1:** User should be able to select one or multiple Dates. Something like marking multiple Dates on a calendar.

[image]

**Step 2**: Once Dates are selected, User can select the timeslots against the selected Dates. Here user should have ability to select multiple time slots on the same Date.

[image]

This way you can accomodate one or more dates with one or more time slots.
p.s. Please ignore the pixelated screenshots :)